# ActionController::UnknownFormat - Capybara spec and AJAX requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, selenium, rspec, capybara

I got problem with my Capybara test. When I run spec with Selenium support (`js: true`) it goes through the instructions until it encounters `click_on` method, which hits `create` controller action and returns error message: "`ActionController::UnknownFormat at /category/items
ActionController::UnknownFormat`", which is probably `respond_with(@items)` issue. In fact, `create` method works fine as well as whole functionality on the server, but into test it crashes. What is more, item creates in the database, so that confirms `create` method works properly.

---

Request information:

`GET   No GET data`

`POST   commit "Do AJAX request"`

`item   {"item_id"=>"12345"}`

`utf8   "✓"`

`COOKIES cookie_policy "accepted"`

---

Spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature "Test in Capybara and Selenium", js: true do
  background(:all) do
  ...seed data
  end

  scenario "my test scenario" do
    visit root_path
    visit '/category/1'
    within first(".css_style") do
        click_on("item_link")
    end
    # we are into item view
    click_on("Do AJAX request") # error
    visit another_view_path
  end
end
```

---

Controller:

```
class ...::ItemsController < ...::BaseController
  respond_to :html, except: ['create', ...]
  respond_to :js, only: ['create', ...]

  def create
    ...
    @item.save
    respond_with(@item)
  end
```

---

Views:

thing view:

`<%= link_to("request", category_items_path(item: {thing_id: thing}), method: :post, class: 'add_item_button', remote: true, name: "animate_item") %>`

create.js.erb:

`if($('#add-item-button').length > 0){
  location.reload(200); 
}`

---

spec_helper.rb

```
...
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'rack/utils'

Capybara.app = Rack::ShowExceptions.new(Sklep::Application)

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
...
```

---

If I forgot about something please let me know.

Comment: Did you solve this? What was the cause of the problem?

Comment: I couldn't solve this problem. It's a still open issue.

Comment: For reasons I don't understand, inserting the line "@javascript" immediately above the scenario, solved a similar problem for me. I have no idea why it works.

Comment: I had a similar issue and resolved it by explicitly adding `format: :js` to the path helper, like so: `category_items_path(item: {thing_id: thing}, format: :js)`